# Is there a neutral current interaction between an antineutrino and an anti-strange quark?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, neutrinos, quarks

I'm doing some revision for an exam and was wondering what the Feynman diagram for a charged current interaction between an antistrange quark - residing in a proton - and an incoming antineutrino would look like.

Also, what  would the neutral current interaction between these two look like?

Comment: You have an extremely nice answer to your title question, about a neutral-current interaction, from annav. However in the text of your question you ask instead about a charged-current interaction. The two are different enough that the appropriate action from you might be to [edit] this question to be unambiguously about the neutral current, mark it as answered (if you're satisfied), and ask a follow-up question about cross-generation lepton-hadron charged currents.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a neutral current interaction between an antineutrino and an anti-strange quark?

The easier formulation of the question is to ask "is there a neutrino-strange quark interaction?"

If the answer is "yes" for particles it will be "yes" for the antiparticles.

Since the neutrino has zero charge and is only weakly interacting it has to be a neutral current, i.e. Z, exchange.

For example here is a [publication:](https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/0310047)

> We study the sensitivity of neutral-current neutrino-nucleus scattering to the strange-quark content of the axial-vector form factor of the nucleon

As the strange quark content of a nucleus is symmetric to the antistrange quark, the study will hold for your "anti-neutrino anti-strange" interaction.

Here is their figure 1.

[image: neutrinonucleus]

They are interested in the modification of the form factors due to the possible scattering off strange quarks, studying the emission of a proton out of the nucleus.